# Programa para calcular descuento en una farmacia

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Necesito resolver este problema en javascript

Una farmacia desea un programa para ingresar el valor de compra y calcular lo siguiente: si el pago se efectúa al “contado”, calcular un descuento del 5%; pero si el pago es con “tarjeta” se incrementa un recargo del 3% al valor de compra. Calcular y visualizar el descuento o recargo según sea el caso y el total a pagar de la compra.

Comment: Si la respuesta cumple tus expectativas, considera marcarla como aceptada con el check del lado izquierdo. Así ambos ganan reputación en la comunidad. Adicionalmente, toma en cuenta las recomendaciones de @BetaM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Se utiliza prompt para Ingresar datos en pantalla, suponiendo que invocara el //codigo javascript desde un archivo html

var valor =parseFloat(prompt("Digite el monto de la compra"));
var tipopago = parseInt(prompt("Digite el tipo de pago \n 1.Contado \n 2.Tarjeta"));

var totalapagar = 0;

/*Si es contado */
if(tipopago == 1)
{
    totalapagar = valor*0.95; 
}

/*Si es con tarjeta */
if(tipopago == 2)
{
    totalapagar = valor*1.03; 
}

console.log(totalapagar);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Marvin, fue justo lo que necesitaba, espero tengas un buen dia :)

Comment: @BetaM ok, muchas gracias por la aclaración, la verdad soy nuevo en esto, solo quería ayudar pero lo tomare en cuenta para la próxima vez

Comment: Marvin, necesito ayuda en otros problemas, hay algun lugar por el que pueda contactarte? Si no te molesta claro

Comment: Hola amigo, si claro escribeme via hangouts, mi mail es marvinpinto0909@gmail.com